# How to change Bootstrap custom-file-input classes background color

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

i am having a problem where i can not change my input[type="file"] background color. I have looked into similar questions but none of them solved my issue. I hope you guys can help me out.

**The code below is my .cshtml**

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="Image" class="control-label"></label>
      <div class="custom-file">
           <input asp-for="Image" type="file" class="custom-file-input" multiple  name="img" >
           <label asp-for="Image" class="custom-file-label">Choose file</label>
           <span asp-validation-for="Image" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>
</div>
```

**The code below is my site.css**

```
.custom-file-input {
    background-color: #f1efdf;
    border-color: #c7c19f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it turns out i should have changed my labels style, so I added style for my label as below:

```
.custom-file-label {
    background-color: #f1efdf;
    border-color: #c7c19f;
}
```

thanks for the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert your file: "site.css" after the bootsrap css like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css">
```

Or use *!important* notation

```
.custom-file-input {
    background-color: #f1efdf!important;
    border-color: #c7c19f!important;
}
```

To read more about:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice but both of them did not work

Comment: Try to clear the cache from browser settings or ctrl + f5 on windows

Comment: I tried it but nope that doesn't work either.